# What is this PHP error?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to upload pictures in the database with a picture. It keeps giving me this error:

```
Array ( [0] => images (1).jpg 
        [1] => images (1).jpg 
        [2] => images (1).jpg [3] => 
        images (1).jpg )
```

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xamppv2\htdocs\fabriek\invullen.php on line 82
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xamppv2\htdocs\fabriek\invullen.php:82 Stack trace: #0 C:\xamppv2\htdocs\fabriek\invullen.php(82): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xamppv2\htdocs\fabriek\invullen.php on line 82

So the idea is to create a webshop where the admin can upload products. Now the only thing not working is uploading multiable pictures into the database. I've searched the error on the internet but all the errors are with much different code and they mostly talk about `` placed wrong. Does anyone know if this could possibly be what is wrong?

Hope anyone can help,

Thomas

The code:

```
$db_server = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_database = "meubelfabriek";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_database", $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $tipe_file1 = $_FILES['image1']['type'];
    $tipe_file2 = $_FILES['image2']['type'];
    $tipe_file3 = $_FILES['image3']['type'];
    $tipe_file4 = $_FILES['image4']['type'];
    $prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
    $naam = $_POST['fname'];
    $beschrijving = $_POST['desc'];
    $maat1 = $_POST['maat1'];
    $maat2 = $_POST['maat2'];
    $maat3 = $_POST['maat3'];
    $maat4 = $_POST['maat4'];
    if ($tipe_file1 == "image/jpeg" || $tipe_file1 == "image/jpg"){
        $aMyUploads = array();
        foreach ($_FILES as $aFile) {
            if(0 === $aFile['error']){
                $newLocation = ''.$aFile['name'];
                if(0 === $aFile['error'] && (false !== move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], $newLocation))){
                    $aMyUploads[] = $newLocation;
                } else {
                    $aMyUploads[] = '';
                }
            }
        }

        print_r($aMyUploads);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `producten` (naam, beschrijving, prijs, maat1, maat2, maat3, maat4, image1, image2, image3, image4) VALUES
    (:naam, :beschrijving, :prijs,  :maat1, :maat2, :maat3, :maat4,'".$aMyUploads[0]."','".$aMyUploads[1]."','".$aMyUploads[2]."','".$aMyUploads[3]."',)");
        $stmt->execute(array(":naam"=>$naam, ":beschrijving"=>$beschrijving, ":prijs"=>$prijs, ":maat1"=>$maat1, ":maat2"=>$maat2, ":maat3"=>$maat3, ":maat4"=>$maat4,":image1"=>$aMyUploads[1], ":image2"=>$aMyUploads[2], ":image3"=>$aMyUploads[3], ":image4"=>$aMyUploads[4]));
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Failed to add data! Images must be inputed at last one and filetype JPG/JPEG')</script>
            <script>setTimeout(\"self.history.back();\",0000);</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This error could not be better described if they tried. Error messages are supposed to be read

Comment: You mix prepared Statements and string concatination. That is no good idea

Comment: Dude check your $stmt . The error is there in the query

Comment: If you rewrite the query statement in a formatted way and use only single quotes for values.

Can you tell me why you have used the colon??

Answer (score 0):

You add some columns by string concatinations but bind the value as Parameter. That will not work. So use Parameter for all columns:

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `producten` (naam, beschrijving, prijs, maat1, maat2, maat3, maat4, image1, image2, image3, image4) VALUES
(:naam, :beschrijving, :prijs,  :maat1, :maat2, :maat3, :maat4,:image1,: image2, :image3, :image4)");
    $stmt->execute(array(":naam"=>$naam, ":beschrijving"=>$beschrijving, ":prijs"=>$prijs, ":maat1"=>$maat1, ":maat2"=>$maat2, ":maat3"=>$maat3, ":maat4"=>$maat4,":image1"=>$aMyUploads[1], ":image2"=>$aMyUploads[2], ":image3"=>$aMyUploads[3], ":image4"=>$aMyUploads[4]));
```